# Ubuntu won't uninstall opera via commandline

Tags: uninstall

I am trying to uninstall opera from my machine running Ubuntu via the command line as described [here](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-programs-ubuntu/) under the section "method 2", however I am not having success. Here is a copy of my console:

```
mathew@mathew-ThinkPad-X220:~$ sudo apt remove opera
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'opera' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
mathew@mathew-ThinkPad-X220:~$ ls /usr/share/applications | grep opera
opera.desktop
mathew@mathew-ThinkPad-X220:~$
```

As you can see, apt thinks opera is not installed, however I can see it in the applications folder. Moreover, I can run opera perfectly fine currently. I'd like to know where I am going wrong in my attempt to uninstall. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it a snap package not deb one?

Comment: installed by dpkg not apt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package names are not always exactly the name of the program you are trying to install.
To install the Opera Browser you have to name the package "opera-stable" in most cases.
To remove them again, you have to name exactly the same package-name that you used for installing your browser.

So first try `sudo apt remove opera-stable` or `sudo apt purge opera-stable`, depending on if you just want to remove the program (1) or also purge its leftover data (2).

If that doesn't work, you have to find out, how the package you've installed with `sudo apt install <package-name>` was called exactly.

You can do that by typing `grep " install " /var/log/apt/history.log`. That displays the command log for apt and you should be able to find the exact package name there. And then just hammer it into the apt remove/purge command and this should work, if I've accessed the issue right :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what package is installed with `which opera`
you may find it's opera-stable or opera-main or something